# Replace Multiple Values Using Rowname as Identifier

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I've been trying to replace the multiple values in a column by their row names. In my actual data, they represent a subjective test which was either recorded as positive or negative at that particular point. I have to reclassify it in my data frame and all I have to do that is the sample ID, which are the row names.

Rather than going in and manually changing each particular value, I was wondering if there was a way to do multiple values at once. I had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338840/how-to-replace-values-in-dataframe-by-id). And I tried this,

```
        dat <- structure(list(A = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "0"), class = "factor"),B = structure(c(1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"),C = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("nd","0", "1"), class = "factor"),D = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L,2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"),E = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0","1"), class = "factor")),.Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 24L))

        dat$result <- as.integer(rowSums(dat[,1:5] == "1")> 0)
        dn <- c("1","5","7","10","14","15","16")
        dat$result[dn] <- "3"
```

Please could someone help me with this.

Comment: `dat3` is not defined. I think it should be `dat`, but I cannot edit that

Comment: @SeGa Thank you, I've edited that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dn` has to be **numeric**, not characters.

When you run the command with dn as characters, you will get only NA values:

```
dat$result[dn]
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

If you change `dn` to numeric, you will get correct values:

```
dat$result[as.numeric(dn)]
# [1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

And then you can assign new values like this:

```
dat$result[as.numeric(dn)] <- 3
dat$result
# [1] 3 0 1 1 3 1 3 1 0 3 0 1 1 3 3 3 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
```

This will not filter the data.frame by row.names but by indeces, but since its an ordered sequence you can just take those indices for the conversion. Or do you need to do the matching based on row.names?

---

To filter by `row.names` you can do something like this:

```
## Filter by rownames
row.names(dat) <- paste0("row_", row.names(dat))
dat

dn <- c("row_1","row_5","row_7")

dat[row.names(dat) %in% dn,]$result <- 3

dat
```

Comment: I need to do the matching based on row names. Thank you for the explanation above, it helps make it really clear to me.

Comment: Just added the filtering by row.names.